# Why the path of the .db files for the neo4j are invalid?

Tags: java, neo4j, dbpedia

I am trying to config my `neo4j` server (on `Mac`) to use `dbpedia4neo` here is the file
`neo4j-server.properties` :

```
################################################################
# Neo4j configuration
#
################################################################

#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# location of the database directory 
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/Users/0x90/dbpedia4neo/index.db

# let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default
# is localhost (only accept local connections). Uncomment to allow
# any connection. Please see the security section in the neo4j 
# manual before modifying this.
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

#
# HTTP Connector
#

# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

#
# HTTPS Connector
#

# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

# Internally generated keystore (don't try to put your own
# keystore there, it will get deleted when the server starts)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

#*****************************************************************
# Administration client configuration
#*****************************************************************

# location of the servers round-robin database directory. possible values:
# - absolute path like /var/rrd
# - path relative to the server working directory like data/rrd
# - commented out, will default to the database data directory.
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd

# REST endpoint for the data API
# Note the / in the end is mandatory
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

# REST endpoint of the administration API (used by Webadmin)
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri=/db/manage/

# Low-level graph engine tuning file
org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties


# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one package name for each mountpoint.
# The listed package names will be loaded under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line
# to mount the org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from neo4j-examples
# under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged


#*****************************************************************
# HTTP logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this property to 'true'.
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=false 

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and archived.
# Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but changing the
# output format is less so, since it is configured to use the ubiquitous common log format
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

The alternatives of `.db` files I have are:

```
./index/lucene-store.db
./index/neostore.relationshipstore.db
./index/neostore.relationshipstore.db/index/lucene-store.db
./index/neostore.relationshipstore.db/neostore.nodestore.db
./index/neostore.relationshipstore.db/neostore.propertystore.db
./index/neostore.relationshipstore.db/neostore.relationshipstore.db
./index/neostore.relationshipstore.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
./index.db
./neostore.nodestore.db
./neostore.propertystore.db
./neostore.relationshipstore.db
./neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
./upgrade_backup/neostore.nodestore.db
./upgrade_backup/neostore.propertystore.db
./upgrade_backup/neostore.relationshipstore.db
./upgrade_backup/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db
```

but when I try them I get this error:

```
./bin/neo4j start
Starting Neo4j Server...WARNING: not changing user
process [31011]... waiting for server to be ready.. Failed to start within 120 seconds.
Neo4j Server may have failed to start, please check the logs.
```

here is the log:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value '/Users/0x90/dbpedia4neo/index.db' for config property 'store_dir': Must be a valid file path.
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting.illegalValue(GraphDatabaseSetting.java:963)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting.illegalValue(GraphDatabaseSetting.java:951)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting$DirectorySetting.validate(GraphDatabaseSetting.java:668)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSetting.validate(GraphDatabaseSetting.java:903)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.ConfigurationValidator.validate(ConfigurationValidator.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.applyChanges(Config.java:125)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config.<init>(Config.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.<init>(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:206)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:77)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:205)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:55)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:103)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:46)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path value should point to the directory containing the database files, not to a single file.

Try just

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/Users/0x90/dbpedia4neo
```

Comment: Even when specified the location to a directory, it is not working for me. I am facing this problem in Ubuntu. Windows it was pretty straight forward, pick the directory using browse button and all works.

Comment: I figured it out later that it is problem with folder permission. Others (users) were not given permission to write. So, did a chmod and then started the service. Everything works fine now.